# Antd - Form.List prefill

Tags: redux, dynamic, antd

I use https://codesandbox.io/s/wonderful-lichterman-br63z and would like to prefill items (with specific data) in the form.

What is the best approach to do this ? I have entries in redux which I would like to get into this dynamic form prefilled.

I know that I can create placeholders, but how can I add specific data ?

What really makes it difficult is that I need a relation between a rendered item and an entry from a data array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see:

https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-hopper-4e6i0?file=/index.js

I hope the solution works for your use case. You will need to replace my hard-coded default values with desired initial values from your redux store. Cheers!

**Update:**

I found a better implementation. Turns out `add` method allows one to set a dynamic fields `defaultValue`

See:

https://codesandbox.io/s/fervent-morning-c9vhk

Comment: How to do it with an iteration ?
So for example, if I want to use an array that has been passed in the props ?

Comment: Construct defaultValue in the child function of Form.List from your prop array.